# Trouble understanding encryption code snippet

Tags: java, hash, cryptography

I am currently working on my final project for school. It´s a client management system, and on the login, I have decided to include an encryption feature so that clients can store their credentials without having to worry about their passwords being out in the open.

I have found this code online, and, since I'm still new on programming, I was wondering if you could give me a little bit of help regarding the meaning of the code.

I know what it does, I just need a little bit of explanation on how it does it.

Here is the code:

```
package Login;

import java.security.MessageDigest;

public class Encrypter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String password = "password";
        String algorithm = "SHA";

        byte[] plainText = password.getBytes();

        MessageDigest md = null;

        try {       
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        md.reset();     
        md.update(plainText);
        byte[] encodedPassword = md.digest();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < encodedPassword.length; i++) {
            if ((encodedPassword[i] & 0xff) < 0x10) {
                sb.append("0");
            }

            sb.append(Long.toString(encodedPassword[i] & 0xff, 16));
        }

        System.out.println("Plain    : " + password);
        System.out.println("Encrypted: " + sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This code calculates a [SHA hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithms) of a password. The naming of the class is wrong, it does not encrypt anything (calculating a secure hash is not encrypting, but a lot of people fail to understand that). Read the API docs of class [`MessageDigest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html).

Comment: divide and conquer, keep that in mind anytime you're trying to understand code.  Go line by line trying to grasp what each one does and then put it all together. When using third party libraries (MessageDigest in this case) search for info/tutorials/code samples to try and understand what it does and how it does it.  It will take time, but it will be far better than relying on someone to explain it to you

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.